# Windows GPO Software Restrictions Policy not working with %TEMP% variable

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

I'm trying to put in some meagre additional malware prevention measures, by restricting the execution of *.exe in a handful of locations -- in particular, the temporary folders that various compression tools unzip to, when a user might choose to open an executable straight from a Zip file.

From the TechNet article, http://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cc786941%28v=ws.10%29.aspx:

> You can use environment variables in a path rule. Since path rules are evaluated in the client environment, the ability to use environment variables (for example, %Windir%) allows a rule to adapt to a particular user’s environment.
>
> ...
>
> A path rule can incorporate the ? and * wildcards, allowing rules such as "*.vbs" to match all Visual Basic Script files. The following examples illustrate the use of wildcards:
>
> - “\DC-??\login$” matches \DC-01\login$, \DC-02\login$
> - “*\Windows” matches C:\Windows, D:\Windows, E:\Windows
> - “c:\win*” matches c:\winnt, c:\windows, c:\windir

I have these Path rules (which I have applied both singularly and in various combinations):

- `%APPDATA%\*.exe`
- `%APPDATA%\*\*.exe`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\*.exe`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\*\*.exe`
- `%TEMP%\*.exe`
- `%TEMP%\7z*\*.exe`
- `%TEMP%\wz*\*.exe`
- `%TEMP%\Rar*\*.exe`

...which theoretically *should* represent executables directly under the user's temp folder, and executables in temp folders named in the manner that Winzip, WinRAR and 7-zip might name their temp folders (e.g. `%TEMP%\7zSF20.tmp\the_file.exe`).

The `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` ones work; the `%TEMP%` ones don't.  Executables *appear* to be blocked under %TEMP% but this is only because, in a default setup, they also match the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\*\*.exe` rule (Temp is under AppData\Local, by default).

I had originally thought this was an issue with wildcards in partial folder names, but it appears this is specific to the use of the %TEMP% variable (hence the rewrite).

The two workarounds I have confirmed (and why I'd prefer not to use them) are:

1. using `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` in place of `%TEMP%`

   - Strictly speaking, this is not correct, as the `%TEMP%` variable can be set to differ from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`.
2. using `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%`

   - Registry-based path rules seem to apply to all subfolders -- I would prefer a slightly lighter touch (so I don't have to go around whitelisting *everything* else)
   - Registry-based rules appear to be limited such that you cannot have anything more specific, e.g. `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%\7z*\*.exe`

     - I have since discovered `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%7z*` will get close (the `\` between the variable and the subfolder should not be specified, and you can't specify a filename mask afterwards)
   - It is also also technically incorrect, as this registry location only contains the value as it should be at the *start* of a process and not what it might be changed to *during the course* of that process -- e.g. it would not apply if you opened a Command Prompt, issued `SET TEMP=C:\` and ran the program from the prompt).

(For what it is worth, I have tried configuring the SRP in both the Computer and User sections of the GPO, both independently and simultaneously, in case one overwrote the other, or `%TEMP%` was resolved differently at Computer and User level.)

What's so special about the `%TEMP%` variable that it would not apply here, whereas something like `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\\wz*\\*.exe` would?

---

### Update:

It appears that the limitation is specifically with the `%TEMP%` environment variable.  I have edited the question, as such.

Comment: It does but if you have the path rules like you wrote you have a typo in there writing `exe` instead of `tmp`

Comment: @lsmooth - looks like a formatting issue -- Markdown was escaping my * and \ characters -- fixed

Comment: Actually, rereading @lsmooth's comment; the `.tmp` is not a typo -- 7zip does indeed create temp *folders* with a .tmp 'extension'.  In any case, I can still execute a file under a folder called `7zABCDE.tmp` or `7zABCDEFG` and I don;t think I should be able to...

Comment: My guess is the problem is `%TEMP%` exists twice and that for the purpose of SRP the System-`%TEMP%` is used instead of the User-`%TEMP%`.

Comment: @lsmooth - I had considered that too, but the system `%TEMP%` is (for me) C:\Windows\TEMP, and I can run an executable from there too -- unless, of course, since there are two versions, SRP doesn't know which to read and so just bails.

Comment: For me is not working the %temp% variable to block the executions of executables files too. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: @MarcCals - Just the ones that I listed in the question.  I went with the registry-key version in the end, as the lesser of all evils, e.g. `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%*.exe`...

Comment: @MarcCals - (minor correction), I went with the registry-key version as `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Envrionment\TEMP%subfolder`, and let SRP determine what was executable.  I couldn't restrict it to *only* *.exe

Answer (score 1):

The program might see a different contents of %TEMP% than you, when you check it in cmd.exe or command.com. Sometimes they are not the same.

But using Environment Variables in Software Restriction Policy is a bad idea anyway, because a malware can change the variable.

Comment: Secure and insecure variable expansion are covered in the Technet article linked to in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to block exe files from %TMP% and %TMP%*\ , it looks weird, but it works here on Win7 pro clients, UAC enabled, no administrative permissions on the current user.

```
%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%*exe
%TEMP%\*\*.exe
```

I tried to use `%TEMP%\Rar*\*.exe` and sucessfully blocked run from `%TEMP%\Rar15\putty.exe` and from `%TEMP%\Rar14.tmp\putty.exe`

I don't think %TEMP% may have anything special. I double checked, the registry key path I use doesn't affect `%TEMP%\Rar*\*.exe`

Comment: Are you saying that `%TEMP%\*\*.exe` works for you?  It doesn't for me.

Comment: Also, the `%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%*exe` looks like it blocks anything in `Temp\fooexe` rather than `Temp`

Comment: Yes, %TEMP%\\*\\*.exe worked for me on the computer i used for tests. Yes the registry path will block fooexe in addition to .exe files but i don't think it would be a blocking situation (never seen a temps folder that ends with exe), i didn't tried with *.exe for the registry path because i had trouble in the past having it apply correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
%HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\TEMP%7z*/*.exe
```

Where you omit the backslash (\) after closing % and then use forward slash (/) for subdirectories

I found this reference:
https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/software-restriction-policies-rule-creation.aspx